# Fill randomly among 4 string a button SetText - Android

Tags: java, android

I've 4 Button.

I've 4 differents string.

I want to fill ramdomly the Text of the 4 button*
How can i code this simply?

Here's the code:

```
            switch(randomInt)
        {
        case 0:
            Button01.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition1());
            Button02.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition2());
            Button03.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition3());
            Button04.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition4());
        case 1:
            Button01.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition4()); 
            Button02.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition1());
            Button03.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition2());
            Button04.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition3());
        case 2:
            Button01.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition3());
            Button02.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition4());
            Button03.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition1());
            Button04.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition2());
        case 3:
            Button01.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition2());
            Button02.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition3());
            Button03.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition4());
            Button04.setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition1());


.... etc
```

I think i can do something else, more simple, any idea?

Thx,

Comment: Manish is correct. The random method should go in Button1.set Text(); Get rid of your methods and replace them the Random method from the Math class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having `getproposition1`, why not have a method in `livreFromBdd` class say `getproposition(int index)` which will return the appropriate string at given index. This way you do not need all those methods.

*Pseudocode:*

1. Have a list of integers with 0 to number of buttons - 1. You can easily populate the list with a loop.
2. Shuffle the list you created at step 1. You can use

   Collections.shuffle().
3. Loop through all buttons. You can create a list of buttons.

   for(int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
       buttons.get(i).setText(livreFromBdd.getproposition(integerList.get(i)); 
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can put the four Strings

```
livreFromBdd.getproposition1();
livreFromBdd.getproposition2();
livreFromBdd.getproposition3();
livreFromBdd.getproposition4();
```

in an ArrayList. Then generate a random value between 0 and list.size()-1 and add the List
entry with the random number index to the first Button and delete this list Entry.Do this for every button. That should work :)